# Why use <T extends Superclass> instead of just Superclass?

Tags: java, generics

Good morning, this is taken from the oracle tutorials,
Suppose we have

```
class Shape { /* ... */ }
class Circle extends Shape { /* ... */ }
class Rectangle extends Shape { /* ... */ }
```

And the method

```
public static <T extends Shape> void draw(T shape) { /* ... */ }
```

My question is as follows, why would you ever use `<T extends Shape>` instead of `Shape`? <s>Don't they return the same exact thing anyway? A Shape in this case</s>.

Comment: The generic modifier `<T extends Shape>` affects only the parameter type for `shape` in your example. It has no effect on the return type, which is always `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of this `draw` method, which doesn't return anything, perhaps you are correct, but suppose you had a generic method that had a return value:

```
public static <T extends Shape> T draw(T shape) { /* ... */ }
```

Now, using the type bound, you can write:

```
Rectangle r = ...
Rectangle r2 = draw(r);

Circle c = ...
Circle c2 = draw(c);
```

On the other hand, if you changed the signature to

```
public static Shape draw(Shape shape) { /* ... */ }
```

You can only write:

```
Rectangle r = ...
Shape r2 = draw(r);

Circle c = ...
Shape c2 = draw(c);
```

or use an explicit cast (which might even fail at run-time, since now `draw` can return any sub-type of `Shape`) :

```
Rectangle r = ...
Rectangle r2 = (Rectangle) draw(r);

Circle c = ...
Circle c2 = (Circle) draw(c);
```

Comment: I understand now, thanks a lot for your input. Shame I can't give you a point yet.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't they return the same exact thing anyway?

Yes, considering the return type is `void` in this case.

This  `<T extends Shape>` enables the method to can accept input of type `Shape` or any subclass of `Shape`.

However, if you had something along the lines of this:

```
public static <T extends Shape> T draw(T shape) {/* ... */}
```

then the receiving type could either be `Shape` or **any** subclass of `Shape`.

Had the return type been a `Shape` then the receiving type can **only** be a `Shape` and not its subclasses. Though you can cast the return value from `draw()` to the appropriate type, this is error prone and with the help of generics, we can remove this burden.